# Make a simple calculator using flex and bison

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I'm trying to make a very simple calculator with flex and bison generators.
It just work on integer numbers.
I compiled the lexer file properly with no errors; but when I compile the parser file, it shows me some warnings:

> - warning: 1 nonterminal useless in grammar
> - warning: 2 rules useless in grammar
> - 21.1-4: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: Line
> - 21.9-1: warning: rule useless in grammar: Line: NWL
> - 22.9-55: warning: 1 nonterminal useless in grammar: Exp NWL

It make the output file after showing these warnings.
I compiled the output files by gcc; it made an **.exe** file.
When I run the **.exe** file and try to calculate, it shows me this error:

> - syntax error

Please help me.

My codes:
***lexer file***

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#define YYSTYPE double
#include <stdio.h>
#include "x.tab.h"
%}
DIG         [0-9]
%%
{DIG}+      { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUM; }
"+"                             { return PLS; }
"-"                             { return MNS; }
"*"                             { return MUL; }
"/"                             { return DIV; }
"\n"                                { return NWL; }
"("                             { return LFT; }
")"                             { return RIT; }
%%
```

***parser file***

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#define YYSTYPE double
int yyerror (char const *s);
extern int yylex (void);
%}
%token  PLS MNS
%token  MUL DIV
%token  NWL
%token  NUM
%token  LFT RIT
%left   PLS MNS
%left   MUL DIV
%%
Exp:    NUM             { $$ = $1; };
Exp:    Exp PLS Exp     { $$ = $1 + $3; };
Exp:    Exp MNS Exp     { $$ = $1 - $3; };
Exp:    Exp MUL Exp     { $$ = $1 * $3; };
Exp:    Exp DIV Exp     { $$ = $1 / $3; };
Exp:    LFT Exp RIT     { $$ = $2; };
Line:   NWL;
Line:   Exp NWL         { printf("%f\n", $1); };
;
%%
int yyerror(char const *s) {
  printf("%s\n", s);
}
int main(){
    int ret = yyparse();
    if (ret){
    fprintf(stderr, "%d error found.\n",ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you surrounding the `#define` and `#include` statements with `{...}` ?  (Top of each file.)

Comment: Were there any more details on the `C` _syntax error_ ? what else did the error message say?

Comment: I think it's not **C** syntax error; Because when I write something in my calculator, it shows me this error: **syntax error** (not anymore).

Comment: You need to look up the `|` operator of Yacc/Bison. What you have written is not a correct way of expressing alternate reductions to the same non-terminal.

Comment: @user207421 It's correct; `foo: bar; foo: qux` is absolutely the same as `foo: bar | qux`. It's just a matter of _style_. Also, the order doesn't matter -- except for determining the start sym when not stated explicitly with `%start sym`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start symbol of your grammar is `Exp`, not `Line`. Either put the `Line` rule first or use a `%start Line` declaration. The `%start` declaration should go before the `%%`, in the same section with the `%token` declarations.

That should get you at the point where your program could handle a first line like `3 + 4` ;-)

If you want it to handle multiple lines, you should add another rule -- example of a fixed grammar section of your `*.y` file, with `Seq` (sequence of lines) being the start symbol:

```
Seq:    /* empty */
|       Seq Line
Exp:    NUM             { $$ = $1; };
Exp:    Exp PLS Exp     { $$ = $1 + $3; };
Exp:    Exp MNS Exp     { $$ = $1 - $3; };
Exp:    Exp MUL Exp     { $$ = $1 * $3; };
Exp:    Exp DIV Exp     { $$ = $1 / $3; };
Exp:    LFT Exp RIT     { $$ = $2; };
Line:   NWL
Line:   Exp NWL         { printf("%f\n", $1); };
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `%empty` to make explicit that a rule RHS is empty.  Much like using `ε` in formal language theory.

Comment: @akim `%empty` is bison-only. I'll put a comment instead.

Comment: (The question was about Bison and Flex.)

Comment: still don't see any reason to use extensions unless necessary -- unlike other bison features like location tracking and reentrancy support, that `%empty` directive doesn't add much value.